# Wrapping the CUDA kernel function with template

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a kernel function with a template (which is from https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).

```
template <typename T, int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce(T *g_idata, T *g_odata, int n) {
  extern __shared__ T sdata[];
  
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int i   = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;
  
  if (i < n) { 
    sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
  }else {
    sdata[tid] = 0;
  }
  if (i+blockDim.x < n) sdata[tid] += g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
  __syncthreads();
  
  //reduction in shared memory
  if (blockSize >= 512) {
    if (tid<256) { if (tid+256 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+256]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (blockSize >= 256) {
    if (tid<128) { if (tid+128 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+128]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (blockSize >= 128) {
    if (tid< 64) { if (tid+ 64 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+64]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  
  if (tid < 32) warpReduce<T,blockSize>(sdata, tid);
  
  // write result for this bloc to global memory
  if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

and this function gets called in the  main function as the following.

```
int main() {
  ...
  switch(n_threads) {
    case 512: reduce<int,512><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case 256: reduce<int,256><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case 128: reduce<int,128><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case  64: reduce<int, 64><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case  32: reduce<int, 32><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case  16: reduce<int, 16><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case   8: reduce<int,  8><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case   4: reduce<int,  4><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case   2: reduce<int,  2><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
    case   1: reduce<int,  1><<<n_block, n_threads, n_threads*sizeof(int)>>>(dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data); break;
  }

  ...
  return 0;
}
```

And I don't like such messy form, and want to wrap it up. What I tried is

```
template <typename T>
__global__ void ReduceWrapper(int n_block, int n_thread, T *g_idata, T *g_odata, int n) {
  switch(n_thread) {
    case 512: reduce<T,512> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case 256: reduce<T,256> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case 128: reduce<T,128> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  64: reduce<T, 64> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  32: reduce<T, 32> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  16: reduce<T, 16> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   8: reduce<T,  8> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   4: reduce<T,  4> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   2: reduce<T,  2> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   1: reduce<T,  1> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
  }
}
```

which I call in the main as the following

```
int main() {
  ...
  ReduceWrapper<int>(n_block, n_thread, dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

But this gives an error during the nvcc compilation

```
error: no instance of function template "ReduceWrapper" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int, int, int *, int *, int)
```

The subtle point in doing so was that whether I should put `__global__` for the wrapper(I put it since `dev_arr` will only could be accessible from the device, but removing the `__global__` comes with the same error during the compilation.

Maybe I cannot wrap the `__global__` function?

Comment: You have never compiled ReduceWrapper  to the required instance at the  translation unit where it is defined, and ReduceWrapper is a host function, not a kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__global__` is a decorator for a kernel.

- You are not invoking `ReduceWrapper` the way you invoke a kernel (right?):

  ```
  ReduceWrapper<int>(n_block, n_thread, dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data);
                    ^
                    missing triple-chevron syntax for a kernel launch
  ```
- A kernel definition that invokes other kernels:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  __global__ void ReduceWrapper(int n_block, int n_thread, T *g_idata, T *g_odata, int n) {
    ^^^^^^
    a kernel definition

    switch(n_thread) {
      case 512: reduce<T,512> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
                              ^^^
                              that is invoking other kernels
  ```

is using [CDP](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism).  if you don't know what that is, then that probably wasn't your intent, and you are probably going down an alley that you are unfamiliar with or had no intention of going down.

You can certainly make what you have work if you drop the `__global__` decorator on your `ReduceWrapper` definition, and make that an ordinary C++ function definition to match your ordinary C++ function call.  For example, this compiles:

```
template <typename T, int blockSize> __device__ void warpReduce(T *sdata, int tid){};
template <typename T, int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce(T *g_idata, T *g_odata, int n) {
  extern __shared__ T sdata[];

  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int i   = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;

  if (i < n) {
    sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
  }else {
    sdata[tid] = 0;
  }
  if (i+blockDim.x < n) sdata[tid] += g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
  __syncthreads();

  //reduction in shared memory
  if (blockSize >= 512) {
    if (tid<256) { if (tid+256 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+256]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (blockSize >= 256) {
    if (tid<128) { if (tid+128 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+128]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (blockSize >= 128) {
    if (tid< 64) { if (tid+ 64 < blockDim.x) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid+64]; }
    __syncthreads();
  }

  if (tid < 32) warpReduce<T,blockSize>(sdata, tid);

  // write result for this bloc to global memory
  if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}

template <typename T>
void ReduceWrapper(int n_block, int n_thread, T *g_idata, T *g_odata, int n) {
  switch(n_thread) {
    case 512: reduce<T,512> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case 256: reduce<T,256> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case 128: reduce<T,128> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  64: reduce<T, 64> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  32: reduce<T, 32> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case  16: reduce<T, 16> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   8: reduce<T,  8> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   4: reduce<T,  4> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   2: reduce<T,  2> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
    case   1: reduce<T,  1> <<<n_block,n_thread,n_thread*sizeof(T)>>> (g_idata, g_odata, n); break;
  }
}

int main(){
  int n_block = 0;
  int n_thread = 0;
  int n_data = 0;
  int *dev_arr = NULL;
  int *dev_arr_block = NULL;
  ReduceWrapper<int>(n_block, n_thread, dev_arr, dev_arr_block, n_data);
  return 0;
}
```

Mostly what I did was drop the misplaced usage of the `__global__` decorator.  Its fairly clear you didn't actually intend that (to be a kernel function definition).

Comment: Ah, the main problem was that I was using a wrong header file! I put the main part of templated functions into the *.cu, and only declared their forms in *.cuh just as what normal C++/C functions without template are recommended to be.

Such a poor mistake to spend hours, but your answer really helped me to narrow down what I was doing wrong and saved my extra hours. Thanks again.